# How can find the caller page for current page in drupal

Tags: php, drupal-6

How can i find the url of the caller page for current page in drupal 6.
Is there any function or class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Solved:I use a form with a hidden input in prev page and pass a specific variable to current page.In main page checked that value of variable is exist or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to get the url of the caller page. but it is having some bugs.

`The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.`